# Are there any good textbooks in recent years about the math of neural networks?

Tags: reference-request, neural-networks

I'm looking into doing neural networks for my mathematics degree's student seminar, but I'm having a hard time finding a textbook to use that is more recent as this field is growing quickly, as well as one that is more math oriented. There are lots of great papers out there, but textbooks are hard to find that don't delve mostly into the Computer Science aspect.

I was wondering if anybody here knows about any such books.

Edit: This has been voted that it needs clarity or details. I am a graduate student in Mathematics and have to do a guided independent study of a field of my choosing, and my advisor suggested as a Comp Sci. dual major that I could do Neural Networks if I can find a textbook that is graduate level in the math way, not the computer science way, so that I can do proofs and whatnot on the board. There are tons of papers out there regarding the subject, but I'm trying to find a textbook, which probably hasn't been written yet, but I'm hopeful. All I've found so far has the beginning math behind the Comp Sci and in no way fleshes out the math, understandably.

In essence, I'm looking for a Math Textbook on Neural Networks that is at the Graduate Level.

Comment: Could the people voting to close this as "Needs details or clarity: This question should include more details and clarify the problem" please suggest what sort of details they would expect to be included here?

Comment: You could take a look at this post [What are the best books to study Neural Networks from a purely mathematical perspective?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397207/what-are-the-best-books-to-study-neural-networks-from-a-purely-mathematical-pers) And also you could ask this on the neighbor community [AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Even though you want a more theoretical book, if you aren't already very familiar with neural networks you should read Deep Learning with Python by Chollet as a quick way to learn a lot about the subject. It's a great, readable book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My professor found a textbook that's very linear algebra heavy called *Linear Algebra and Optimization for Machine Learning A Textbook* by Charu C Aggarwal. This is what we've decided to use. It was published in 2020.